# Merge drivers don't work when merging into default branch

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a default branch called `prod` and `master` is my dev branch. I've configured a merge driver `ours` via `git config merge.ours.driver true`. That's what was added to my config:
**config:**

```
[merge "ours"]
    driver = true
```

I want `cfg.json` to be untouched when merging, so I've also configured, committed, and even pushed `.gitattributes` to both branches:
**.gitattributes:**

```
cfg.json merge=ours
```

Now, this only works if I merge `prod` with `master` (I'm on `master`, I run `git merge prod`), but it doesn't work the other way around (I'm on `prod`, I run `git merge master`, `cfg.json is changed regardless of all my efforts`)

I believe I tried every single StackOverflow solution on this problem, tried many articles, but it just doesn't work in this very specific scenario. Is this an intended behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question if this is what's happening, but I think you're running into a quirk of how Git merge works.  In a merge, Git considers only three points: the two heads, and the merge base, which is usually the most recent common ancestor.

When Git does a merge, if a file is changed on one side and unchanged on the other, Git takes the changed version without invoking any merge functionality at all, including custom merge drivers.  That's because, when you use a three-way merge, if one side is changed and the other is unchanged, the changed version is adopted.

In your case, what you're trying to do is a bad idea and the Git developers advise people against doing it.  If you want to have two different versions of a config file, either use a single template file and generate an ignored config file from it, or include both versions into the repository and just choose which one to use in each environment by a means outside of the repository.  It's not really going to work to try to keep two versions of the file like this when you're doing merges.

Comment: Looks like you were right about that Git "quirk". I like the generator solution, I wrote a small Node.js script that reads, configures and writes an ignored config file based on inline arguments (process.argv). I've created some scripts in my package.json and now can quickly switch between modes. Thank you for the idea!